# Parsing Protocol Buffers, written in Java and read in Python

Tags: java, python, protocol-buffers

I am dealing with a situation where the protocol buffers have been written to in Java, but I have to read them using Python.

I have the .proto file with me, I have compiled it using protoc, and generated the python class file.

The proto file has multiple messages, for example:

```
message ABC {
    optional int64 id = 1 [default = -1];
    optional int64 hello6 = 2;
    optional bool hello5 = 3 [default = true];
    optional int32 hello4 = 4;
    optional int64 hello3 = 5;
    optional int64 hello2 = 6;
    optional int64 duration = 7;
}
message DEF {
    optional int64 hello = 1;
    repeated ABC abc = 5;
    repeated String xyz = 6;
  }
```

While parsing in python using .ParseFromString.

I am getting the error:

> google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Tag had invalid wire type.

I think the issue is because of absence of explicit delimiters, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: **Protocol Buffer** doesn't have type `String`. Proper type is `string`

Comment: How large is the serialized proto that you can't decode? If it's small, including it in your question would be helpful. Otherwise, can you include the first few tens of bytes?

Comment: Please show **Java** and **Python** code.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue for me this worked:

In Java you do:

```
yourGeneratedClass.toByteArray()
```

In Python you do(parsed message in result):

```
result = your_pb2.yourGeneratedClass()
result.ParseFromString(body)
```