# Serialize multiple protobuf messages in java and desesrialize them in Python

Tags: java, python, protocol-buffers

I want to store a bunch of protobuf messages in a  file, and read them later.

In java, I can just use 'writeDelimitedTo' and 'parseDelimitedFrom' to read and write to a file. However, I want to read it in Python, which only seems to have a 'ParseFromString' method.

Some SO questions are very similar, such as,  [Parsing Protocol Buffers, written in Java and read in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507714/parsing-protocol-buffers-written-in-java-and-read-in-python), but that is only for a single message: not for multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the proto guide it is written that you need to deal yourself with the size of your message:

> Streaming Multiple Messages
>
> If you want to write multiple messages to a single file or stream, it
>   is up to you to keep track of where one message ends and the next
>   begins. The Protocol Buffer wire format is not self-delimiting, so
>   protocol buffer parsers cannot determine where a message ends on their
>   own. The easiest way to solve this problem is to write the size of
>   each message before you write the message itself. When you read the
>   messages back in, you read the size, then read the bytes into a
>   separate buffer, then parse from that buffer. (If you want to avoid
>   copying bytes to a separate buffer, check out the CodedInputStream
>   class (in both C++ and Java) which can be told to limit reads to a
>   certain number of bytes.)

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques

A simple solution could be for you to serialize each proto in base64, on a new line in your file.

Doing so, it would be pretty easy on python to parse and use them.